# Rails two decimal places with 0 not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I enter a price of 3.50 into my form, rails saves it to the database as 3.5 but when I enter anything else that doesn't have a zero at the end like 3.51 it saves it as 3.51. I need 3.50 to be returned as json if 3.50 is entered.

In my simple form, I am using this for the input

```
<%= f.input :price, :value => number_to_currency(f.object.price, :precision => 2) %>

Schema

 t.decimal  "price",              :precision => 10, :scale => 2
```

Any ideas on why the zero is dropping off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 0 is not significant. It has nothing to do with rails. Type `3.50` in the console, and it will return `3.5`. `3.50` is just the string representation of your number. When it's converted to a float, there's no point in having the 0.

Why do you need to 3.50 to be returned? An alternative would be to add it yourself when creating the json.

Comment: Thanks @Robin, I need it to be returned as 3.50 because in my iOS app it is a price that needs to look like $3.50. As you suggest I will try to do this in iOS.

Comment: Yep, it's probably better if your api doesn't have to care about that. This should be fixed in the "front end".

Answer (score 1):

As long as a number is stored as a number, most databases will keep it the simplest number possible. As soon as the number becomes a string, that's the time to ensure any leading or trailing zeros.